# Arrows not working using explicit navigation - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation

I found out we could use Navigation mode in UI. I've used Explicit but I can't change from an input field to another.

I've got a hierachy like that:

```
Canvas
    Panel
    BackButton
    InputNamePrefab
       InputNameChapter
    InputDescriptionPrefab
       InputDescriptionChapter
```

And in my component InputNameChapter, I've set on Select On Down my InputDescriptionChapter component. I've done the opposite with Select On Up.

But nothing happens when I press any of my arrows ? Can you explain me why ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include your code please?

Comment: Hello, I don't have any code since everything is done by editor, but I managed to solve ! Was dropping wrong game objects in my Select on down and on up